# Empty / Redundant Payment Methods

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

After upgrading a Magento 1.3 database to 1.9 I am seeing empty payment methods in admin. How can I find and remove redundant / empty payment methods from the database?

In the screen shot you can see the first 7 payment methods are selectable but empty.

[image: Screen shot of empty payment methods in customer groups]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by installing an old version of the RicoNeitzel PaymentFilter module in Magento 1.9. Emptying the allowed_payment_methods table in customter_group and installing the latest version resolved the problem.